# How can I build the source code for Spring Boot and Spring Framework using Gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build

I am new to *GRADLE*. Currently, I am studying spring-framework and spring boot. I have managed to compile the spring boot source code and run a spring boot demo that relies on spring-boot-starter. spring boot utilizes spring-framework code, and I would like to incorporate some personalized logging into spring-framework while debugging my spring boot demo.

I am unsure about how to merge the spring boot source code with the spring framework source code using GRADLE. What steps should I take?

I'm just getting started with *GRADLE*, and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.